# How to remove space between elements in a string using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to remove space between 2 elements in an XML using xslt. I initially converted my xml to string using content-as-a-string() function. This helped me to remove the indentation of the xml. However there are single spaces between each element as given below. The requirement is to remove the spaces between 
**> <**.

```
<Employee> <EmployeeName>ABC</EmployeeName> <EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID> <EmployeeDate>11/13/2015</EmployeeDate> </Employee>
```

The output i need is as below:

```
<Employee><EmployeeName>ABC</EmployeeName><EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID><EmployeeDate>11/13/2015</EmployeeDate></Employee>
```

Any help in getting the correct XSLT is appreciated. Also I can use only xslt 1.0 version.
Regards
Anooja

Answer (score 3):

A simple identity transform plus a template that matches text nodes and applies `normalize-space()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/> </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this will normalize spaces in ALL text nodes.

Comment: Hi Jim,Thank you for the response. However, as mentioned in my question, i have converted my xml to a string now. So when i apply this xslt, it is still not removing the space. The xml is stored in a variable, after converting to a string. <HighwayMessage><Employee> <EmployeeName>ABC</EmployeeName>  <EmployeeID>123</EmployeeID>
 <EmployeeDate>11/13/2015</EmployeeDate> </Employee></HighwayMessage>. So the input of xslt is this variable HighwayMessage which contains the actual data. Hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use XSLT in this scenario. Hence used java ReplaceAll function and used "//s+" to replace all the spaces, which includes new line, space etc.

Regards
Anooja